# Changing System Time to three hours ahead and then back to default

Tags: java, command-line

I been trying to change system time to three hours ahead and then back to default but i seem to not get the time i want. Isn't  cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")); suppose to set the time to America/Los_Angeles Timezone?

```
public static void changeSystemTime() throws Exception {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));

    System.out.println("Current time is " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
    System.out.println("3 Hours from now is " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    runtime.exec("cmd /c Time " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
}

public static void changeSystemTimeToDefault() throws Exception {

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    Date date = new Date();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));

    System.out.println("Timezone for LA is " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    runtime.exec("cmd /c Time " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: Question title says 2 hours ahead but in your actual question it says 3?

Comment: Sorry about that, I just edited it

Comment: FYI, if you are changing the computer clock merely for the purpose of testing, be aware that the new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 provides for passing a custom [Clock](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) object. That custom Clock can provide falsified date-time values for the purpose of mocking data for testing.

Answer (score 1):

you actualy do not add 3 hours in method changeSystemTime();

reason:

```
String time = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println("Current time is " + time);

cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
// here you again work with the initial time, the 3 hours are not added to it
System.out.println("3 Hours from now is " + time);
```

do this:

```
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
// get new time
System.out.println("3 Hours from now is " + cal.getTime());
```

Comment: Just edited it thanks, but i seem to get the initial time wrong. Right now its 9:39 AM but it prints out
Current Time is 16:38

Comment: My time right now is 19.05 and it prints 19.05 and then 22.05 (when I add 3 hours), so it works ok for me.

Comment: Try this part only and tell me what time does it print for you:     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current time is " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

Comment: Ok.. I tried running in eclipse and it works fine but when i run in command line it gives it wrong time

Comment: I think that could be another interesting question for StackOverflow people :)

Comment: I had to set the timezone with dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")); for some reason setting the timezone in calendar gave me different time

Answer (score 0):

You can use JNI for setting the system time. This would work on Windows. You need to know JNI and C.

This is the JNI function, the prototype will be generated by the javah utility

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_TimeSetter_setSystemTime
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jshort hour, jshort minutes) {

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetLocalTime(&st);  
st.wHour = hour;      
st.wMinute = minutes;  
SetLocalTime(&st);
```

}
The Java JNI wrapper would be

class TimeSetter {

```
public native void setSystemTime( short hour, short minutes);

static {
    System.loadLibrary("TimeSetter");
}
```

}
And finally, to use it

public class JNITimeSetter {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    short hour = 8;
    short minutes = 30;

    // Set the system at 8h 30m

    TimeSetter ts = new TimeSetter();
    ts.setSystemTime(hour, minutes);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i don't really know JNI and C